# Load balance active TCP sessions to AWS Aurora RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, tcp, amazon-aurora

I currently have a problem with properly load balance open TCP sessions (created by the RoR application) to dynamically created Aurora Postgresql read-replicas.

The issue with this is when TCP connections are already established to one read-replica, another read-replica is created. After that traffic from the first replica will not be distributed evenly to second one, since TCP connections are already established with first replica.

Attached chart represents current infrastructure setup. Please note that between read-replicas (servers) and application (client) there is a load balancer, provided by the Aurora service, which is based on DNS round-robin.

[image]

I've tried [pgbouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/), [pgpool](https://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) and multiple Ruby gems ([makara](https://github.com/instacart/makara), [fresh_connection](https://github.com/tsukasaoishi/fresh_connection)), but none of them were able to load balance nor eliminate long lived TCP connections..

I went through many articles and they helped investigate and confirm the issue; however none of them present a solution.

So... as you can see I've tried obey this problem from application and network perspective, unfortunately without luck. Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've figured this out and the fix had to be applied on application level in order to stop keeping long live TCP connections.

Particulary in Ruby I had to set [idle_timeout](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) and [reaping_frequency](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) parameters. However [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/manage-connections) you can find parameters for other programming languages.

Hope it help someone in future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could scale your load balancers along with the database instances.

```
                +----+     +--------+
             -> | LB | --> | Server |
+--------+ /    +----+     +--------+
| Client |     
+--------+ \    +----+     +--------+
             -> | LB | --> | Server |
                +----+     +--------+
```

As the client connects in a round robin fashion to the load balancers, the load balancers will do their jobs to limit to the total database connections per server. A [simple routing policy in DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-simple) with multiple load balancing hosts should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @Miles Elam for your answer! Unfortunately I am not in control of load balancer, since it is provided by AWS Aurora service and I am unable to create custom one per each database replica as I would need to update somehow replica endpoints in configuration of LB. However in more flexible environment your idea would work. I am thinking of limiting connections on database side and once new replica is added queued connections will be targeted to it. Stay tuned!

Comment: It looks like `max_connections` limitations for databse didn't improved situation. Application still persistently connects to just one read-replica.